# Api get all option within sub entity

Tags: api, civicrm-entity, apiv4, fieldoptions

get all options from a sub entity named payment_instrument within a entity called OptionGroup

Answer (score 3):

The best way to learn how to use the API is the Api Explorer which is built into CiviCRM (find it in the **Support -> Developer** menu. It will write the following code for you:

```
$optionValues = \Civi\Api4\OptionValue::get(TRUE)
  ->addWhere('option_group_id:name', '=', 'payment_instrument')
  ->addWhere('is_active', '=', TRUE)
  ->execute();
foreach ($optionValues as $optionValue) {
  // do something
}
```

With this GUI:

[image]

Comment: I have used the API Explorer 4 but could not reach the options within a sub entity of an entity. Is there really no way to get that data out?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QYyR40ZR Here is my return message and there are options under payment_instrument that i would like to view

Comment: You will need to use Option value as the entity to fetch the options